# How to transition out of parent UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have the following code, which setups and shows a UIViewController to be embedded into a UINavigationController:

```
private func transitionToMainVC() {
  let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SpacesVC())

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.show(vc, sender: self)
  }
}
```

Now, in`SpacesVC` I want to `show()` another UIViewController, but outside of the "parent" `UINavigationController`.

When I use the following code in `SpacesVC`:

```
// Called by a button touch up inside
@objc private func transitionToMainVC() {
  let vc = NextVC()

  self.show(vc, sender: self)
}
```

It transitions to `NextVC` but it shows the navigation bar at the top of the screen; i.e. the new view controller is still embedded under the `UINavigationController` defines in the first snippet.

I am aware of the possibility of hiding the navigation bar in `NextVC` as such:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  navController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

But I want to `show()` the `NextVC` without embedding it in the navigation controller, since I won't need that anymore. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) instead of `show`.

```
func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, 
    animated flag: Bool, 
  completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```